# How to list the used file-numbers in VB.NET 3.5?

Tags: vb.net, vb6-migration, file-handling

Does anybody know how to enumerate the used file-numbers [as in FileOpen(filenum, ...)] in Visual Basic .NET 3.5 (VS2008)?

The situation is: I'm doing "a quick port" (just to bring it up a supported architecture) of an old VB6 WinForms application (it's "just a tool" really, not a full-on app) to VB.NET using Visual Studio 2008's automatic translator, over the .NET 3.5 framework. The existing code stores "records" in parallel arrays, the index of which is the output-file-number, and output-files are opened and closed "ad hoc"... so I can't "just" use FreeFile (I could, but it'd basically be a rewrite, which we won't get paid for).

After translating I've got an "invalid filename or number" error upon FileOpen'ing filenum=350 for Ouput... I know the filename is valid, and doesn't already exist. I tried (just for debugging) setting filenum=FreeFile and that worked (i.e. the file was opened)... so I figure that filenum=350 is already open, but how to tell BY WHAT? A listing of the used filenums -> names would give a huge leg-up.

I suspect this just isn't possible, but I've got to ask anyway, because it was save ever-so-much time, effort, and thought if it is possible, so here we are.

Cheers all. Keith.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be wrong here, but I don't think that file numbers can be greater than 255.

Comment: Correct. File numbers can't be greater than 255.

Comment: Doh!!! I googled the error message, found http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa231024(v=VS.60).aspx = Visual Basic FOR APPLICATIONS Reference - 
Bad file name or number (Error 52) which says: blah, blah • Out of the range of file numbers (1,511)... and thought, well the numbers not too big, so it's gotta be used. Thanks guys!!! ioBeer++;